# SELECT DISTINCT CAST (CASE (WHEN X IN)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT) AS INTO Returns Duplicate Records

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to select a list of patients who have a diabetes diagnosis code at any point in the past ~ 1 1/2 years and return either a 1 (patient does have a diabetes diagnosis code) or 0 (patient does not have a diabetes diagnosis code) into a hash table for later use. I am getting the 1's and 0's that I wanted, however for many patients I am returning both a 1 and a 0. I've tried troubleshooting as best I can, but haven't been able to return just a single value per patient. Here is the query I've been using.

```
IF object_id('tempdb..#t4') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #t4
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(
             CASE 
                  WHEN (diag_code IN ('250.00','250.01','250.02','250.03','250.10','250.11',
                        '250.12','250.13','250.20','250.21','250.22','250.23','250.30','250.31',
                        '250.32','250.33','250.40','250.41','250.42','250.43','250.50','250.51',
                        '250.52','250.53','250.60','250.61','250.62','250.63','250.70','250.71',
                        '250.72','250.73','250.80','250.81','250.82','250.83','250.90','250.91',
                        '250.92','250.93','357.2','362.01','362.02','362.03','362.04','362.05',
                        '362.06','362.07','366.41','648.00','648.01','648.02','648.03','648.04',
                        '111552007','111558006','11530004','123763000','127013003','127014009',
                        '190321005','190328004','190330002','190331003','190336008','190353001',
                        '190361006','190368000','190369008','190371008','190372001','190383005',
                        '190389009','190390000','190392008','190406000','190407009','190410002',
                        '190411003','190412005','190416001','190417004','190418009','190419001',
                        '190422004','193184006','197605007','198609003','199223000','199227004',
                        '199229001','199230006','199231005','199234002','201250006','201251005',
                        '201252003','23045005','230572002','230577008','237599002','237600004',
                        '237601000','237604008','237613005','237618001','237619009','237627000',
                        '25907005','26298008','267379000','267380002','2751001','275918005','28032008',
                        '28453007','290002008','309426007','310387003','311366001','312912001','313435000',
                        '313436004','314537004','314771006','314772004','314893005','314902007','314903002',
                        '33559001','34140002','359611005','359638003','359642000','360546002','371087003',
                        '38542009','39058009','39181008','408539000','408540003','413183008','414890007',
                        '414906009','420414003','420422005','421750000','421847006','421895002','422183001',
                        '422228004','422275004','423263001','424736006','424989000','425159004','425442003',
                        '426705001','426875007','427089005','428896009','42954008','44054006','4627003',
                        '46635009','50620007','51002006','5368009','54181000','57886004','59079001','5969009',
                        '70694009','73211009','74263009','75524006','75682002','76751001','81531005','81830002',
                        '8801005','91352004','9859006','31','E10.36','E11.36','E11.9','E13','E13.32','E13.33',
                        'E13.34','E13.35','E13.43','O24.42')) 
                     THEN 1 
                  ELSE 0 
             END AS bit) as DM,
            patientid
INTO #t4
FROM patient_diag
WHERE dateofservice >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '01-01-2014')
```

Is this something that would be better solved using `EXISTS`? I tried that as well, but struggled to return the desired results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this something that would be better solved using EXISTS?

Yes.  If a patient had both codes that *are* in the list and codes that *aren't* you'll get both 1s and 0s.  EXISTS would work, but a MAX might be faster:

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(
             CASE 
                  WHEN (diag_code IN ...
                        'E13.34','E13.35','E13.43','O24.42')) 
                     THEN 1 
                  ELSE 0 
             END AS bit)) as DM,
            patientid
INTO #t4
FROM patient_diag
WHERE dateofservice >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '01-01-2014') 
GROUP BY patientid
```

Note that maintenance will be easier (and performance may be better) if you put all of those codes in a separate table rather than hard-coding them in a query.  Or, if there's a master codes table, you could add an attribute that is used by the query.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Had to change `END AS bit` to `END AS int` and then I was good to go!

Comment: @scribbles Very good.  You could have also done the cast after the max if you wanted to output the value as a bit, but use whatever works for you.